Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 24.10 server - device shows up on mac as a g_ether gadget, but not as webcam (uvc)
I am trying to create a "virtual webcam" on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W with Ubuntu 24.10.
I am working through this tutorial:
https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_the_UVC_gadget_driver_in_Linux
where they want to create a "virtual webcam" to stream video as if it was coming from a locally attached camera.
I ran through the script (attached below) all the way to the end and everything worked, but the device is not showing up on my mac as a USB device. I have been able to configure this same device as a g_ether gadget by just loading the modules, and it enumerates on the mac, so I know that my hardware/cabling is correct.
The dmesg is showing:
[  923.318812] configfs-gadget.g1 gadget.0: uvc: uvc_function_bind() [  923.320674] dwc2 3f980000.usb: bound driver configfs-gadget.g1

However, the mac does not see it show up:
% system_profiler SPUSBDataType USB:

USB 3.1 Bus:

Host Controller Driver: AppleT6000USBXHCI

USB 3.1 Bus:

Host Controller Driver: AppleT6000USBXHCI

USB 3.1 Bus:

Host Controller Driver: AppleT6000USBXHCI

I saw the note about needing to do:
echo peripheral > $UDC_ROLE
and I suspect that is where the problem lies in that it is not setting the device in peripheral mode, even though I did specify that in /boot/firmware/config.txt as dr_mode=peripheral.
The script points set UDC Role like: UDC_ROLE=/sys/devices/platform/soc/78d9000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/role
Since my controller is 3f980000.usb, I went in to /sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb but there is no ci_hdrc.0 folder and I searched for a file named role, but nothing was found:
root@raspberrypi:/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb# find . -name role -print
Any guidance on this would be great!
script:
#!/bin/bash

# Variables we need to make things easier later on.
#

set -e

# First load the libcomposite module
modprobe libcomposite

UDC=`ls /sys/class/udc`
UDC_ROLE=/sys/devices/platform/soc/78d9000.usb/ci_hdrc.0/role
CONFIGFS="/sys/kernel/config"
GADGET="$CONFIGFS/usb_gadget"
VID="0x0525"
PID="0x0102"
SERIAL="0123456789"
MANUF=$(hostname)
PRODUCT="UVC Gadget"

mkdir -p $GADGET/g1
cd $GADGET/g1
echo $VID > idVendor
echo $PID > idProduct

mkdir -p strings/0x409

echo $SERIAL > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo $MANUF > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo $PRODUCT > strings/0x409/product

mkdir configs/c.1

mkdir configs/c.1/strings/0x409

CONFIG="configs/c.1"
FUNCTION="uvc.0"
mkdir functions/$FUNCTION

mkdir -p functions/$FUNCTION/streaming/uncompressed/u/360p

cat <<EOF > functions/$FUNCTION/streaming/uncompressed/u/360p/dwFrameInterval
666666
1000000
5000000
EOF

mkdir functions/$FUNCTION/streaming/header/h
cd functions/$FUNCTION/streaming/header/h
ln -s ../../uncompressed/u
cd ../../class/fs
ln -s ../../header/h
cd ../../class/hs
ln -s ../../header/h
cd ../../class/ss
ln -s ../../header/h
cd ../../../control
mkdir -p header/h
ln -s header/h class/fs
ln -s header/h class/ss
cd ../../../

echo 2048 > functions/$FUNCTION/streaming_maxpacket

ln -s functions/$FUNCTION configs/c.1

echo $UDC > UDC

echo "Done. Listing /dev/video*"

ls /dev/video*

I have tried configuring the device in both g_webcam and in configfs (per the script) and in both cases, the device shows up as being bound to the UDC in dmesg, but the device is not being seen in the host (mac).
I have tried using Raspberry Pi OS Lite 64 (Debian 12 Bookworm) and Ubuntu 24.10 and get the same results. It will enumerate as g_ether, but not g_webcam or through configfs.
